# store long string in to MySQL using python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, scrapy

It is part of my scrapy project. and it is big so can not able to put whole script here but I can try to make thing clear as possible.
python version is 3.6.2

I am trying to store string that have emoji into MySQL database here is my database schema

Create database:

```
DATABASE = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8'"
```

Alter database:

```
ALTER_DB = "ALTER SCHEMA `testdb`  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4"
```

Table replyes, threads, user:

```
TABLES = {}
TABLES['replyes'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `replyes` ("
    "  `reply_no` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    "  `thread_name` TEXT NOT NULL,"
    "  `reply_text` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,"
    "  `replyer` varchar(30) NOT NULL,"
    "  `reply_reactions` int(5),"
    "  `reply_date` varchar(11) NOT NULL,"
    "  `add_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),"
    "  PRIMARY KEY (`reply_no`)"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")


TABLES['threads'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `threads` ("
    "  `thread_no` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    "  `topic_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,"
    "  `group_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,"
    "  `thread_name` TEXT NOT NULL,"
    "  `thread_text` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,"
    "  `thread_starter` varchar(30) NOT NULL,"
    "  `thread_reactions` int(5),"
    "  `thread_replyes` int(5),"
    "  `thread_date` varchar(11) NOT NULL,"
    "  `thread_url`  varchar(150) NOT NULL,"
    "  `add_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),"
    "  PRIMARY KEY (`thread_no`)"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")

TABLES['users'] = (
    "  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` ("
    "  `user_no` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    "  `user_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,"
    "  `user_posts` int(11),"
    "  `user_comments` int(11),"
    "  `visibility` varchar(8),"
    "  `user_location` varchar(30),"
    "  `user_since` varchar(30),"
    "  `groups` int(3),"
    "  `group_names` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,"
    "  `group_urls` LONGTEXT,"
    "  `add_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),"
    "  PRIMARY KEY (`user_no`)"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")
```

Insert Query:

```
insert_replyes = """INSERT INTO replyes(thread_name, reply_text, replyer,reply_reactions, reply_date) values("{thread_name}","{reply_text}", "{replyer}", {reply_reactions}, "{reply_date}")"""
insert_thread = """INSERT INTO threads(topic_name, group_name, thread_name,thread_text, thread_starter, thread_reactions, thread_replyes, thread_date,thread_url) values("{topic_name}","{group_name}","{thread_name}","{thread_text}", "{thread_starter}",{thread_reactions},{thread_replyes}, "{thread_date}", "{thread_url}")"""
insert_user = """INSERT INTO users(user_name, user_posts, user_comments,visibility, user_location, user_since, groups, group_names, group_urls) values("{user_name}", {user_posts}, {user_comments}, "{visibility}", "{user_location}", "{user_since}", {groups}, "group_names}", "{group_urls}")"""
```

I am inserting data that have various characters like emoji, special char($ ,`\xc2\xa0 ~ \xc2\xa0 \xc2\xa0 ~ \xc2\xa0 \xc2\xa0 \xc2\xa0` etc.).
I have tried many `CHARACTER SET` for database and also table.

And the whole thing is working accept some data is not stored into data base

Working data:

```
# For replyes
INSERT INTO replyes(thread_name, reply_text, replyer,reply_reactions, reply_date) values("Is this positive??!! Plz help!! ","b'I see it in both! Congratulations \n '", "Skymomof4", 1, "2018-04-26")


INSERT INTO replyes(thread_name, reply_text, replyer,reply_reactions, reply_date) values("Sticky: Rules, Tools and Helpful Links. Updated with working photos","b'Thank you so much for ALL the info, you are amazing!!! '", "chandresteen", 0, "2018-04-26")

# For users
INSERT INTO users(user_name, user_posts, user_comments,visibility, user_location, user_since, groups, group_names, group_urls) values("chandresteen", 7, 605, "Public", "Coconut Creek,FL", "September 2013", 10, "['Big Kids', 'Getting Pregnant - Trying to Conceive ', 'High-Tech Methods for Getting Pregnant - IVF, ICSI, FET', 'May 2015 Birth Club', 'November 2018 Birth Club', 'Preschoolers', 'Soy Isoflavones, Clomid, Vitex & Femara Girls!', 'Toddlers', 'Trying to Conceive Community', 'TTC/Pregnancy South Africa']", "['https://community.babycenter.com/groups/a155/big_kids', 'https://community.babycenter.com/groups/a6720413/getting_pregnant_-_trying_to_conceive', 'https://community.babycenter.com/groups/a696465/high-tech_methods_for_getting_pregnant_-_ivf_icsi_fet', 'https://community.babycenter.com/groups/a6748015/may_2015_birth_club', 'https://community.babycenter.com/groups/a6768388/november-2018-birth-club', 'https://community.babycenter.com/groups/a145/preschoolers', 'https://community.babycenter.com/groups/a6731007/soy_isoflavones_clomid_vitex_femara_girls', 'https://community.babycenter.com/groups/a135/toddlers', 'https://community.babycenter.com/groups/a43905/trying_to_conceive_community', 'https://community.babycenter.com/groups/a6758887/ttcpregnancy_south_africa']")

# For threads
INSERT INTO threads(topic_name, group_name, thread_name,thread_text, thread_starter, thread_reactions, thread_replyes, thread_date,thread_url) values("Getting Pregnant","b'Getting Pregnant - Trying to Conceive '","Sticky: Rules, Tools and Helpful Links. Updated with working photos","b'Welcome to the BBC   Group Getting Pregnant! Below are some links to some threads that would help some of you lovely ladies! Good Luck on your TTC   journey. \xc2\xa0 ~ \xc2\xa0 \xc2\xa0 ~ \xc2\xa0 \xc2\xa0 \xc2\xa0 If there is something not here that you would like to see please feel free to message me. Sorry that the list is so short! Babydust ladies!! '", "~Dovah~",59,6, "2018-04-26", "https://community.babycenter.com/post/a60866779/sticky_rules_tools_and_helpful_links._updated_with_working_photos")
```

above are working that actually in the database

Not working data

```
# For threads
INSERT INTO threads(topic_name, group_name, thread_name,thread_text, thread_starter, thread_reactions, thread_replyes, thread_date,thread_url) values("Getting Pregnant","b'Getting Pregnant - Trying to Conceive '","Struggling with TTC Process","b"This has officially turned into more of a supportive post surrounding the TTC   process when its taking longer. It's been sooooo difficult trying to go through this the past 1.5 yrs... waiting to finally get our BFP   while others come and go with their journies. OP:\xc2\xa0 Hey ladies.... any input would be greatly appreciated. Hubby and I have been TTC   going on month 15, I think about 20 cycles as mine are shorter. I've been to an RE   and slowly have been getting everything done to see if anything is wrong.... nothing is so far. All that's left is an HSG test. Even hubby has super sperm... yet we're not pregnant. The Dr's office wants to put me on birth control for a week or so and start me on Clomid then do an injection for ovulation followed by IUI. This all feels so quick and sudden that I'm just all over the place with whether to go ahead and I need to let them know basically tomorrow! (No pressure!) My struggle is that a part of me feels that if God wanted it, it would have happened already.... so is doing something like IUI   going against God? I'm so scared that if i do, the baby will have problems and I don't know if I can handle that. On the other hand, I don't want to wait years and years for another baby! It crushes me every time someone else is pregnant and I'm still longing for mine. Thoughts??? "", "PaoPao820",6,50, "2018-04-26", "https://community.babycenter.com/post/a68579914/struggling-with-ttc-process")

# For replyes
INSERT INTO replyes(thread_name, reply_text, replyer,reply_reactions, reply_date) values("Is this positive??!! Plz help!! ","b'Thank you!! I took another this morning and it looks exactly the same, not any darker so fingers crossed \xf0\x9f\xa4\x9e\xf0\x9f\x8f\xbb\xf0\x9f\xa4\x9e\xf0\x9f\x8f\xbb '", "BeBeNBabY", 0, "2018-04-26")

# For user
INSERT INTO users(user_name, user_posts, user_comments,visibility, user_location, user_since, groups, group_names, group_urls) values("~Dovah~", 544, 12988, "Public", "Whiterun, Skyrim", "February 2012", 3, "['Crocheting Mamas', 'Getting Pregnant - Trying to Conceive ', "Getting Pregnant's GOT PREGNANT!"]", "['https://community.babycenter.com/groups/a90405/crocheting_mamas', 'https://community.babycenter.com/groups/a6720413/getting_pregnant_-_trying_to_conceive', 'https://community.babycenter.com/groups/a6762598/getting_pregnants_got_pregnant']")
```

this is how I creates the insert query from scrapy items all code to store and create insert statement is written in piplines.py under project's pipline
code to store:

```
import mysql.connector as sql

config = {
    'user': 'root',
    'password': 'root',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'charset': "utf8",
    'use_unicode': True,
}
connection = sql.connect(**config)

curser = connection.cursor()

string = insert_thread.format(
    topic_name=item['topic'],
    group_name=item['group'],
    thread_name=item['name'],
    thread_text=item['text'],
    thread_starter=item['starter'],
    thread_reactions=item['reactions'],
    thread_replyes=item['replyes'],
    thread_date=item['date'],
    thread_url=item['url']
)
cursor.execute(string)
connection.commit()
```

All Not working data gives same error it looks like below

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/media/mnthn/work/Office/2018/james_mcallister/babycenterforum/babycenterforum/pipelines.py", line 43, in process_item
    self.insert_user(item, spider)
  File "/media/mnthn/work/Office/2018/james_mcallister/babycenterforum/babycenterforum/pipelines.py", line 100, in insert_user
    self.insert(string)
  File "/media/mnthn/work/Office/2018/james_mcallister/babycenterforum/babycenterforum/pipelines.py", line 132, in insert
    self.cursor.execute(string.replace('\n',''))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 566, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 537, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 436, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Getting Pregnant's GOT PREGNANT!"]", "['https://community.babycenter.com/groups/' at line 1
```

I have tried many times I have tried to enter data manually by using python shell, i searched on the internet for whole day I have been trying to solve this about four days but nothings actually work

Comment: it seems pretty clear that it comes from `"Getting Pregnant's GOT PREGNANT!"]"` like the error says, your quotes are probably not done correctly. Also, you need to escape single quotes in SQL, this is done by doubling them up, so it should be `Getting Pregnant''s` which will print as `Getting Pregnant's`. Escaping also works inside simple quotes, so you could write : `'Getting Pregnant''s GOT PREGNANT!'`

Comment: I think changing your line to `"['Crocheting Mamas', 'Getting Pregnant - Trying to Conceive ', 'Getting Pregnant''s GOT PREGNANT!']"` should work.

Comment: This is a minor detail, but i'm curious as to why you need 4GiB for your user.group_names ? :3

Comment: I did it for testing may be it solves the problem because I have seen detail that have huge length of text. It is first sat as MEDIUMTEXT also I have updated back to MEDIUMTEXT.

Comment: Thanks your solution kinda worked but it needs more effort and different logic but your solution hinted me it so simple if i did check my own question after posting I could have identify that